# Windows Auth into page; App Pool user into database

Tags: authentication, asp-classic, iis-7.5

Is it possible, using a classic ASP application hosted in IIS 7.5, to use Windows Authentication on the page (so I can access LOGON_USER) but use the app pool identity to connect to the database?  If I turn on Anonymous Authentication and set it to run as the app pool identity, I can connect to the database, but I can't get the LOGON_USER.  If I disable Anonymous Authentication, I can get the LOGON_USER, but I can't connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Coworker found this:  Apparently setting Physical Path Credentials under Advanced Settings on the app will also translate to the network communications with the database.  So, anonymous auth off, windows auth on, physical credentials set to service account.

Not really sure why that works, since I would have expected Physical Path Credentials to affect only interactions with disk..